# How to set TextField width?

Tags: dart, flutter

I nested my TextField inside a Container with width 10.0, but the textfield is still taking up the whole width of the device.

```
Widget _reviewBody() {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        width: 10.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
        child: TextField(
          onChanged: (text) {
            setState(() {
              reviewBody = text;
            });
          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
          maxLines: null,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Add your thoughts here',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Burnt.hintTextColor),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Burnt.lightGrey)),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Burnt.primaryLight, width: 1.0)),
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How do I set the TextField width?

Edit: Turns out SliverToBoxAdapter does magic, so I've used media query to set a padding on my container. Maybe I'm not supposed to use SliverToBoxAdatper, if someone can explain the right thing to do that would be great thanks.

Edit2: Actually I came up with an even better idea, I just put my Container inside a Row and made the Row center my 100.0 wide Container

Comment: did you tried to use SizedBox?

Answer (score 2):

I tried something like this

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 30, right: 30),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Inserisci la tua email",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    labelText: "Email",
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Utils.blackColor, fontSize: 20),
                    border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Utils.greyColor)),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid))),
                controller: nameController,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23)),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

pu textfield and a container in a column as a child, then wrap children with flexible widget give them flex property